# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended while being called by controller

Tags: sql, sybase, jdbctemplate, sap-ase

```
   @Override
  public List<TbCsradminBillpayGroup> findAllMerchantCategory() {
    String SQL = "SELECT * FROM guest.guest.TB_CSRADMIN_BILLPAY_GROUP";  
    List<TbCsradminBillpayGroup> bpGroup = jdbcTemplate.query(SQL, new MerchantCategoryMapper());
    return bpGroup;
  }
```

When my controller class try to call this method, i hit the error "SQL command not properly ended". I am relatively new to jdbctemplate btw. anything that i miss out on the query?

i tried all of the method that is available but still it is not solved. please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicated schema specifier ('guest') in your query, fix it in following way:

```
String SQL = "SELECT * FROM guest.TB_CSRADMIN_BILLPAY_GROUP";
```

Comment: the duplicated schema is because i have a database name "guest" and inside the database i have two schemas which is "dbo" and "guest". when i remove one of it i got ORA-00942: table or view does not exist instead.

Comment: Specifying database name in SQL query is incorrect. You specify database once when opening connection and all queries are executing in context of that database. So you should fix the query as I suggest anyway. Then the other question arise why you get 'ORA-00942: table or view does not exist '. Could you try to fire the query in any SQL client when connected to the same database?

Comment: Are you sure you actually have 'guest' schema? Could you try the query 'SELECT * FROM TB_CSRADMIN_BILLPAY_GROUP'?

Comment: i do have a guest schema. anyway i fire the statement in sqldeveloper and it can work.but when i try to call it in controller it always shows the error as the title. btw it is using jdbctemplate to connect to the database

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you don't query table like database_name.schema_name.table_name

I tried reproducing the error:

```
select ora_database_name from dual; -- this gives me database name


select sys_context( 'userenv', 'current_schema' ) from dual;  -- this gives me current schema name
```

Now, when i tried using approach as you mentioned in question:

```
select * from MyDBName.MySchemaName.TestTable;
```

Got below error:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
```

Correct way is to use schema name followed by table name;
In your case:

```
String SQL = "SELECT * FROM guest.TB_CSRADMIN_BILLPAY_GROUP";
```

Comment: sorry my bad..i tag the wrong tag..its actually for syabase